Is there a bug on the Area 51 stats?
On the Area 51 stats for Bitcoin Stack Exchange it says there are zero 'avid users.'  I know that that is completely wrong because by their definition there are more than enough 'avid users.' This may be a temporary glitch, but what is going on?

There was an outage of the site earlier today, perhaps it also messed up the stats on Area51.
Now, the stats show 481 avid users.

